# Laravel - How to hide div based on specific condition from the database

Tags: laravel

In my Larave-5.8 project, I am working on leave application. Specifically on the employee resumption date.

I have this model class:

```
class HrLeaveRequest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hr_leave_requests';
    protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'company_id',
              'employee_id',
              'department_id',
              'leave_type_id',
              'leave_day',
               'is_resumed',
              'commencement_date',
              'resumption_date',
              'leave_status',
              'created_by',
              'created_at',
          ];  
}
```

Controller

```
public function service()
{
try {     
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $leaverequests = HrLeaveRequest::where('leave_status', 4)->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('company_id', $userCompany)->get();
     return view('service-default')
            ->with('leaverequests', $leaverequests);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
        return back();
        }         
}
```

By default, is_resumed is 0.

What I want to achieve is that, the

```
<div class="row">
```

below should only visible when

> is_resumed = 0

and

> created_at

is less than or equals to resumption_date

and as soon as is_resumed is 1, the

service-default.blade

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="callout callout-info">
            <center>
                <strong>
                </strong>
            </center>
        </div>                
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-3">
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <a class="btn btn-info float-right"  href="">
                    Resumption Activation
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>                  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Kindly that created_at (datetime) and resumption_date (date datatype) are dates  while is_resumed is tinyint.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you blade file you do condition like below:

> First this will get new dateTime Object, and next compare that object
>   for differance.

```
@php
$created_at = $leaverequests->created_at;
$resumption_date = $leaverequests->resumption_date;
$datetime1 = new DateTime($created_at);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($resumption_date);
@endphp


@if($leaverequests->is_resumed == 0 && $datetime1 < $datetime2)
 show your html code
@endif
```